# How do I properly format a Spark dataframe for input to LDA fitting?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, lda

I have a dataframe which is formatted like so:

```
Index | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3
21      5.0        1.0         6.0
5       4.0        2.0         3.0
```

but for an input to LDA().fit(df) I need a dataframe formatted like so:

```
id | features
21   [5.0, 1.0, 6.0]
5    [4.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I'm used to using Pandas, but new to using PySpark and can't find a good way to get to proper format. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[21, 5.0, 1.0, 6.0], [5, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0]], 
    ['Index', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3'])

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(
    ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3']
).setOutputCol("features")

assembler.transform(df).show()

+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
|Index|Feature1|Feature2|Feature3|     features|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
|   21|     5.0|     1.0|     6.0|[5.0,1.0,6.0]|
|    5|     4.0|     2.0|     3.0|[4.0,2.0,3.0]|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```